# Display animated SVG file in SwiftUI

Tags: animation, svg, swiftui

I am trying to put in animated .svg images in a WatchKit SwiftUI project.
Unfortunately I could neither find a way to convert the svg to png "frames", nor a way to directly use the svg files as an animation.
Is there a way to use animated .svg images in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think .svg is natively supported. Possible workarounds:

- A WebView should be able to load it.
- Convert to .pdf/.png/.jpeg
- https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit

Not sure if there is a very simple solution for WatchKit.

However, WatchKit has a `WKInterfaceImage.animatedImage(with:duration:)` that lets an ImageView animate through a set of images. 
you still have to convert the frames of your SVG to PDF/PNG/JPEG.

This might be a good starting point for you: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfaceimage#1652345

Comment: You'll have to wrap an SVGKit view to use it with SwiftUI; there's a tutorial on doing that at https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit

Comment: WebView is not available in WatchKit.
How do I go about converting the animated(!) svg to a pdf? I have not found a solution online.

Comment: I missed WatchKit somehow.

Comment: Thanks for WKInterafaceImage Edit. I will check that out right now.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my dilemma, however it is far from optimal:

**1. Create HTML page to display the animated svg**

```
<object data="file.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

You should set the page's background color to the  background color you want to use where you need the animated image. I set it to black.

**2. Creating a png sequence**

Using the tool ScreenToGif (screentogif.com) I recorded the html file inside chrome with maximum zoom. The tool allows you to export to many different formats, one of them being a sequence of independent "frames" as single png files.

**3. XCode: Create a Timer and image array**

```
var animatedIcons: [UIImage]! = (0...9).map { UIImage(named: "imageName\($0)")! }
@State var index: Int = 0
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.2, on: .main, in: .default).autoconnect()
```

**4. Let the Image  receive timer updates**

```
Image(uiImage: self.animatedIcons[index])
   .resizable()
   .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
   .onReceive(timer) { (_) in
        self.index = self.index + 1
        if self.index > self.animatedrIcons.count - 1 {
                self.index = 0
        }
```